# Converting Simplenews Subscribers to Users

Tags: 7, users, emails

I was wondering if there is a way to convert SimpleNews subscribers into actual Drupal users?

Currently, I have something similar going on using custom fields in the user-register form, but wanted to know if I can leverage the Simplenews module for my needs.

I want to create a block where users can register to receive weekly e-mails in which they receive information about our weekly ad.

Cheers,

Elm

Answer (score 0):

this may be useful
http://bouteillenicolas.com/expertise-drupal/simplenews-save-subscribers-info

All you have to do is use rules, create a webform, and then use rules that handdles that webform and create the suscriber and the the user using the information sended through the webform

Answer (score 0):

From the simplenews api:

```
/**
 * Act after a new subscriber has been created.
 *
 * @ingroup subscriber
 */
function hook_simplenews_subscriber_insert($subscriber) {

}
```

This is a hook function that is executed every time there is a new subscriber. You must use this function in your module replacing 'hook' by your module name. Try the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_simplenews_subscriber_insert().
 *
 */
function mymodule_simplenews_subscriber_insert($subscriber) {
  $user = new stdClass();
  $user->name = 'happyUser';
  $user->mail = $subscriber->mail;
  $user->pass = 'password';
  $user->status = 1; // omit this line to block this user at creation
  // save the user
  $user = user_save($user);
  // connect the subscriber with the user
  $subscriber->uid = $user->uid;
  simplenews_subscriber_save($subscriber);
}
```